# Why don't my arrow keys work in vim under iTerm?

Tags: terminal, text-editor, iterm

They work just fine if I use Terminal and start a vim session, but under iTerm I have to resort to using H-J-K-L to do left-up-down-right movement.

In both Terminal and iTerm TERM=xterm-color. My `.vimrc` is quite lean and there are no key bindings set in there that would causing this problem.

iTerm v0.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

1. From the **Bookmarks** menu item, select **Manage Bookmarks...**.
2. Choose the **Default** bookmark and click the edit icon.
3. Change the **Keyboard** setting to **Global**.

Comment: I got the same problem on iTerm2. There's no Bookmarks menu :(

Comment: @Wei: They're called Profiles in iTerm2. Profiles -> Open Profiles... and from there you can load the xterm defaults for Keyboard for the profile(s).

Comment: @Ian, thanks. I found the settings but loading the xterm defaults didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @WeiHu: The original suggestion from sentinel was to load the Global setting, not the xterm one, and I expect this carries over to iTerm2 - I'll try as soon as I install iTerm2. I know that Ian C. wrote xterm, but maybe that was a typo.

Comment: For iTerm2, there's a FAQ section:
http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/faq
I use "Report Terminal Type: xterm-256color" together with the default xterm keybindings; you can try the ones from Terminal.app, but keybindings seem to be unrelated.
For me the only important thing was to set Alt to behave as +Esc instead of Meta, but that shouldn't apply to arrows (for me, it fixed Alt-B and friends under screen).

Comment: Sorry to post to this old thread, but I have just hit this problem, and I have tried all suggested fixes with zero improvement. 1) I have removed the plist preferences file and restarted iterm<br>
2) I have selected the Terminal.app compatibility in the keys section of the profile - again it did not help.<br>
3) Installed the latest stable and tested then the latest beta - no improvement<br>
4) Works perfectly with the inbuilt Terminal application - no changes required Any pointers and help gratefully recieved as this is proving to be a real pain.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me.

In iTerm2:

- Profiles -> Open Profiles...
- Edit Profiles...
- Keys tab
- From Load Preset... drop-down, pick Terminal.app compatibility

Comment: Thank you Gerald, you are a Gentleman and a Squire.

Comment: This seem to work so far, but I'm wondering what's the root cause ... )

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed:

```
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>^[A <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>^[B <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>^[D <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>^[C <Nop>
```

**Note:**

The **"^["** characters must not be typed, instead you get them by doing: <kbd>⌃</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and pressing the corresponding cursor arrow position (up,down,left,right).

**Tested with: iTerm2 (Build 1.0.0.20140629)**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this sorted out with iTerm2 Build 3.0.15 and the following excerpt from my .vimrc:

```
" Map alternate key combination for Esc.
noremap <c-[> <Esc>
" Map arrow keys for nomal mode.
nnoremap <silent> <Esc><Up>A <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <Esc><Down>B <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <Esc><Right>C <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <Esc><Left>D <Nop>
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest (and probably best) way to solve this is to switch iterm profile keymapping to "Natural editing" preset.

1. Go to preferences
2. Go to profiles
3. Go to keys
4. Go to keymappings
5. From preset dropdown select natural editing preset